# iOS Simulator in-app browser crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I'm implementing a Facebook based application and I'm testing it on iOS Simulator. When I click to login on Facebook button an in-app browser appears, then I enter my username and password and finally push the login and the permission button, but this error message appears in the Console:

```
WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: 
<NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]:
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

After that nothing happens on the screen, but when I restart my app, I'm authenticated from Facebook and I can use my app normally.

How can I fix this issue? Will this happen on a real device?

Comment: Anything that happens in the iOS Simulator will likely happen on an actual device; looking at that error, it almost definitely will. Is it possible for you to test it on a device?

Comment: Yes, most likely it will happen on a real device because the app is trying to insert nil object. Please try to verify the properties for nil objects like I've suggested below to see if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem: I tried to access to the user data in the - (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView method, but the - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView hadn't been called before the first one, so the user data was not fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app is trying to cache some of their Facebook data in one of your objects. Perhaps you need to make a `nil` verification, then if any of the required fields are not set in Facebook, you'd see the crash you mentioned.

Try to verify if `self.userProfile` or other properties are non-nil.

Comment: I used this sample file: https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/blob/master/FBLoginUIControlSample/FBLoginUIControlSample/LoginUIViewController.m
In the - (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView method I remove the loginView from the super view.
I don't know which variable I should check :(

Comment: Are you using this sample code as it is, or have you made any modifications?

Comment: In the - (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView method I remove the FBLoginView object from the super view. And I also don't use the additional sample variables like profilePictureView. Firstly this code worked well, but yesterday I restore the simulator (delete cache) and I got the login to facebook. Before the restore there was no error, because the session  was cached and the login wasn't used.